# Resetting databases with having OneToOneField crossing different applications in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, innodb

I'm getting the following error when I run `./manage.py reset app1`:

```
Error: Error: app1 couldn't be reset. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlreset app2'. That's the SQL this command     wasn't able to run.
The full error: (1217, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails')
```

with a model which has OneToOneField with another model in a different app (let's say app2). I'm using MySQL InnoDB. More accurately, OneToOneField is declared in app2's model.

How do I get rid of this error?

**Update:**
The output of sqlreset command is:

(app1)

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE `app1_instance`;
DROP TABLE `app1_instancegroup`;
CREATE TABLE `app1_instancegroup` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- some more fields
)
;
CREATE TABLE `app1_instance` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `belongs_to_id` integer NOT NULL,
    -- some more fields
)
;
ALTER TABLE `app1_instance` ADD CONSTRAINT `belongs_to_id_refs_id_455b868f` FOREIGN KEY (`belongs_to_id`) REFERENCES `app1_instancegroup` (`id`);
CREATE INDEX `app1_instance_belongs_to_id` ON `app1_instance` (`belongs_to_id`);
COMMIT;
```

(app2)

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE `app2_team`;
CREATE TABLE `app2_team` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `instance_group_id` integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    -- some more fields
)
;
ALTER TABLE `app2_team` ADD CONSTRAINT `instance_group_id_refs_id_39493b52` FOREIGN KEY (`instance_group_id`) REFERENCES `app1_instancegroup` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the output of django-admin.py sqlreset app2? What was it?

Comment: I had to drop the foreign key constraint manually via mysql console. Is there any support for this kind of jobs in Django officialy or by 3rd parties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step that can make manually resetting easier is (and avoid the dread ERROR 1217):

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0
```

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html:

> InnoDB does not allow you to drop a
>   table that is referenced by a FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint, unless you do SET
>   foreign_key_checks = 0. When you drop
>   a table, the constraints that were
>   defined in its create statement are
>   also dropped.